# How to remove the main content area from home page?

Tags: magento2.2, magento-2.2.1

How do I remove this section from **homepage**?

```
<main id="maincontent" class="page-main"></main>
```

All of my home page content is done in blocks and I'm now stuck with this large empty **maincontent section** on the **homepage** that I can't seem to get rid of.

I'm on Magento 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

> **Try This**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**cms_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="content" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried in cms_index_index.xml something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="wtite your container name" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Having trouble with where that file should be placed and what the block name is for that maincontent area